# How to add multiple columns to angular mat-list

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

Is there a way to build an angular mat-list with multiple columns? 
In the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview) it looks like the list support only 2 columns at max.
This is what I try to achieve (with a checkbox at the start of each column) : 
[image]

PS: I tried to use the flexlayout grid but didn't work well inside the mat-list.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-angular-material-5enooc) demo

Thanks

Comment: Can you put your code what you have done so far?

Comment: i added a demo link in my post

Comment: In your docs link the first example shows a list with 3 rows. In a `mat-list`, you create a row by adding a `mat-list-item`. Your stackblitz example has only 1 `mat-list-item` and therefore only 1 row. That's all obvious. Please revise your post and be more clear about what your problem is.

Comment: I think you mean multiple columns (instead of rows). You can accomplish this with a `mat-list`, but the `mat-table` is better suited for multiple columns. Have you considered that?

Comment: My bad I meant columns,unfortunately I can't use mat-table in my case

Answer (score 0):

Remove the matLine attributes and they will stay in one row. You could then use fxFlex like: fxFlex="25%" in the tags to format your columns appropriately.